# Why are leaves blank on all rb trees?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I'm working on data structures. There is something I do not understand about Red and Black trees. He always writes about the following features about these trees. But in all examples the values of the leaves are null. Why is that not in the features either. Why "All leaf nodes are black and blank." not?

Red/Black Property: Every node is colored, either red or black.
Root Property: The root is black.
Leaf Property: Every leaf (NIL) is black.
Red Property: If a red node has children then, the children are always black.
Depth Property: For each node, any simple path from this node to any of its descendant leaf has the same black-depth (the number of black nodes).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter if all nodes are keyless and black or not.

If the nodes could be any color and/or empty, the asymptotics would not change at all, since red children cannot have red parents and all internal nodes have associated keys.

All paths would still have lengths that are at most a factor of two different in total number of keys, though now that would be 2L+2, rather than 2L for the longest path compared to the shortest path (of length L).

Comment: My question is "Why are all leaf nodes black?" not. My question is "Why are the contents of all leaf nodes null?" I think you got it wrong.